# Which pokemon has the most major advantage vs other pokemons in pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

In pokemon go, which pokemon has the most advantage vs other pokemons? I'm looking for the best overall average pokemon that can beat a majority of other pokemons without much weaknesses.

Comment: Mewtwo is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Definitely any legendary of full-evolved Psychic type, in first gen they were the best type to use.

Comment: Use [this](https://img.pokemondb.net/images/typechart-gen1.png) chart to create a team of pokemon where you would have at least one pokemon that was super effective against each of the other possible types. Then you can just switch out to the pokemon that is most effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Move Type effectiveness chart Gen 1]

I could be wrong but, using http://pokemondb.net/tools/type-coverage to help me. I created this graph to show the most effective types of attack, so if your mon knows thunder or blizzard you'll be golden, if it knows sludge bomb or draco meteor, I'd get a new pokemon. This chart only counts gen 1 pokemon but gen 6 type attacks. Enjoy